# Python Break Inside Function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, break

I am using Python 3.5, and I would like to use the `break` command inside a function, but I do not know how.
I would like to use something like this:

```
def stopIfZero(a):
    if int(a) == 0:
        break
    else:
        print('Continue')

while True:
    stopIfZero(input('Number: '))
```

I know that I could just use this code:

```
while True:
    a = int(input('Number: '))
    if a == 0:
        break
    else:
        print('Continue')
```

And if you don't care about the `print('Continue')` part, you can even do this one-liner:
`while a != 0: a = int(input('Number: '))`(as long as a was already assigned to something other than 0)
However, I would like to use a function, because other times it could help a lot.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your `stopIfZero` function is trying to do more than it should. Try to focus the function on one, and only one, task.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually, this is done by returning some value that lets you decide whether or not you want to stop the while loop (i.e. whether some condition is true or false):

```
def stopIfZero(a):
    if int(a) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        print('Continue')
        return False

while True:
    if stopIfZero(input('Number: ')):
        break
```

Comment: I knew that you could do this, but was wondering of you could do it in a different way. I was hoping for a yes, that you could do this, it stinks that you can't. Thank you for your answer, it is what I was asking, even if it is not the yes that wanted.

Comment: @nedla2004 What applies to `break` also applies to `continue`.

Answer (score 8):

A function can't `break` on behalf of its caller. The `break` has to be syntactically inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `return`, not `break`.

[`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) is used to stop a loop.

> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the smallest enclosing for or while loop.

[`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) is used to exit the function and return a value. You can also return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` keyword is meant to be used as in your loop example only and must be inside the loop's scope.

Update your function to return `True` or `False` only instead:

```
def is_zero(value):
    if value == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Then in your loop, simply use like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        value = int(input("Enter a value (0 to exit): "))
    except ValueError:
        # user entered a non-numeric value (e.g. a letter)
        # try asking again immediately instead of crashing :)
        print('Use numbers only, please')
        continue

    if is_zero(value):
        break

    print('Good entry. Continuing...')
```

Your `stopIfZero` function is also somewhat overloaded (i.e. has more than just 1 responsibility) because it does more than just check if a value is zero or not. For example, it:

1. converts the arguments into an `int`,
2. prints a message, and
3. is not re-usable in other parts of your program

Take those reasons into consideration to improve your code.